# HANA hdbindexserver start issue after power outage

Tags: hana

There was a power outage for our 5+1 node HANA cell cluster.

After we booted up the servers, tried to start the HANA DB.

During HDB start with SIDADM we can see on the nodes 2-3-4-5:

> FAIL: process hdbindexserver HDB Indexserver not running

So of course trying to start hdbindexserver with hand with SIDADM:

```
cd /usr/sap/SIDADM/HDB0x/exe; ./hdbindexserver
```

But this just produces error:

> /usr/sap/SIDADM/HDB0x/foobar003/trace> cat indexserver_alert_foobar003.trc
>
> ...
>
> [14268]{-1}[-1/-1] 2017-10-09 19:55:34.593776 e TrexNet          Communication.cpp(00501) : no internal interface found
>
> [14287]{-1}[-1/-1] 2017-10-09 19:56:01.428226 e Checkpoint       CheckpointMgr.cc(00244) : Skip versions garbage collection savepoint: transaction distribution work failure: snapshot timestamp synchronization failed
>
> [14287]{-1}[-1/-1] 2017-10-09 19:56:22.467184 e Row_Engine       transdtx.cc(01410) : Unexpected ltt exception thrown: transaction distribution work failure (at foobar/ptime/storage/tm/transdtx.cc:1410 )
>
> [14287]{-1}[-1/-1] 2017-10-09 19:56:22.467427 f PersistenceLayer PersistenceController.cpp(00679) : startup failed exception  1: no.71000145  (ptime/storage/tm/transdtx.cc:1512)
>
> snapshot timestamp synchronization failed
> ...

The IPs are up. There is 1 TB of RAM.

**The question:** what could cause hdbindexserver to fail to start?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the indexserver process wasn't able to bind the internal network interface again:

> Communication.cpp(00501) : no internal interface found

I'd look into the other tracefiles and the system log to check whether the configured NI is up and available.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the persistence storage (disk where data and log file resides) is not responding within time and hence it's getting timed out. Can you check if you can access the data file and log file from the server.

Also check is network I/O slow or disk I/O slow  on that server, causing the synchronization to timeout.

You can try stopping the system completely and try to bring HDB on just that server first to check if above issue exists.